# How can I make it so my mute command will take a discord ID as an identifer instead of @ them

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
    let user = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]));
    if (!user) return message.channel.send("Please put a valid member or a user ID for me to mute")
```

Okay I this code is from my mute command and when I try to do `.mute [there discord id] [time]` it always returns with the "please put a valid member or a user id for me to mute". I don't get it like I can only use there discord id and put it in this format `<@there-discord-id>` and then it works like I just want to put there raw discord id and let the rest of the code run.

Comment: Have you considered the fact that guild members cache might not be populated with the id you are looking for? Why not use `await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0])` instead of `message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])`? The [`fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) method will by default check the cache, if it is not present it will fire a web request.

Answer (score 0):

Here mine, might help you (d.js v13)

```js
let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);

if(!member) return sendEmbed('Mention a member or use user ID')
```

now you can use it like this
`{cmd} 1234567890`
`{cmd} @guildMemberMentions`

P.S. ignore `sendEmbed` it just my Embed constructor function